# Degeneracy of spherical harmonics eigenfunctions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, spherical-harmonics

I'm working through Griffiths' *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics* (2nd edition) and I'm trying to solve problem 4.24 b. In this problem, you're supposed to first find the normalized eigenfunctions to the allowed energies of a rigid rotator, which I correctly realized should be spherical harmonics. Then, you should find the degeneracy of the $n^\text{th}$ energy level and I don't know how to do this. The correct answer says $2n+1$ but they never explain how they found this answer and for me it feels like it's taken out of the blue, but maybe I don't know enough about quantum numbers yet. I would appreciate it a lot if someone could explain how the degeneracies work for spherical harmonics as eigenfunctions for the $L^2$ operator.

Comment: Are you privy to the definition of the degeneracy of an eigenvalue of a linear operator?

Comment: @Djamillah I don't know that Griffiths book and I saw many complaints of it. But, spherical harmonics are eigenfunctions of two operators, $L^2$, and $L_z$. These functions are denoted as $Y_l^m (\theta, \phi)$, and for each value $l$ there are $2l + 1$ values of $m$, i.e. $m = l, l-1,..., 0,... -(l-1), -l$. You can see all this in the Wikipedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics#Laplace.27s_spherical_harmonics. But, the typical notation for the spherical harmonics uses the indexes $l$ and $m$ there is no $n$ (which usually has another meaning).

Comment: (continuation) Could it be that Griffiths used the notation $n$ instead of $l$? Let me suppose so. Then, if you have a quantum system which displays a different energy for each value of $l$, but the energy doesn't depend also on $m$, the energy level $l$ is degenerated. That means, more than one single state corresponds to it, in our case $2l+1$ states. $m$ is called magnetic number, because for some systems a magnetic field can split the energy level $l$ into $2l+1$ sub-levels, one sub-level for each value of $m$.

Comment: @Sofia: Long comment. Why not an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not sure why this was bumped to the community page, since the relevant answer is contained in bits and pieces in the preceding comments and answer.

Anyway, in summary: @Sofia is correct. Griffiths uses a non-standard convention in this question, replacing $l$ with $n$. ‘Degeneracy’ just means that there are multiple states with the same energy.

**Explicitly**

Since the Hamiltonian for a rigid rotor of length $a$ with two particles of mass $m$ at each end is

$\hat{H} = \frac{\hat{L}^2}{ma^2}$,

and since the spherical harmonics are the eigenfunctions of the $\hat{L}^2$ operator,

$\hat{L}^2Y^m_l(\theta,\phi) = \hbar^2 l(l+1)Y^m_l(\theta,\phi)$

(where the $Y^m_l(\theta,\phi)$ are the spherical harmonics) we have that the (degenerate) energy values are

$E_l = \frac{\hbar^2l(l+1)}{ma^2}$.

Then, purely because of the *definition* of the spherical harmonics (i.e. that there are $2l+1$ values of $m$ for every value of $l$), we can see that the degeneracy is $2l+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Griffiths 2nd edition Equation [4.118] and [4.119]:

$$L^2 f_\ell ^m=\hbar ^2\ell (\ell+1)f_\ell ^m$$

and $$ L_z f_\ell ^m=\hbar m f_\ell ^m$$

where $\ell =0, 1/2, 1, 3/2, \ldots $ and $m=-\ell ,\ldots ,\ell$.

There is are degeneracies in the $L^2$ operator since the eigenvalue only depends on the $\ell $ index.

There are a total of $2\ell +1$ indices in the $m=-\ell ,\ldots ,\ell$.

Section 4.3 p.178, the eigenfunctions $f_\ell ^m$ mentioned here in these two equations are the Spherical Harmonics $Y_\ell ^m$.

Footnote 17 references Schiff Quantum Mechanics for a detailed derivation of the wave-equation solutions to the Hydrogen atom, however, this should be the 3rd edition of that book for page 93.

I am still trying to get a sense of why the half-integer solN's of $\ell $ are sometimes dropped, and sometimes not (planning to ask a professor). I believe it has something to do with Spin.

In Exercise #4.24, for example (the massless Rigid-Rotor problem), Griffiths does indeed swap the $\ell $ index symbol for an $n$.

Comment: Half-integer solutions for orbital angular momentum are dropped because otherwise the wave function (spherical part) wouldn't be continuous on the circle (a rotation of $2\pi$ would get a minus sign otherwise).

Comment: I thought a -1 from a $2\pi $ rotation was something we wanted with a spin-1/2 particle like an electron? (Perhaps I am confusing orbital momentum and spin).

Comment: The spherical harmonics have the form $f(\theta)e^{-i2\pi\cdot m}$, $m$ being the $L_z$ eigenvalue. If half-integer, rotation of $2\pi$ bring back a minus sign.